# How do I make my tabs fade blue when i hover over it - Bootstrap 3 - EnjinSite

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Title says it all, my current html for the bootstrap navbar is as follows

This is my html currently: http://pastebin.com/83aUVeBM

My site currently; pixelcmc.enjin.com
at the top of my site, that is my bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the default bootstrap setting for tab :

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
background-color: #EEEEEE;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now you can override the default style by adding this line to your CSS file :

```
.nav > li > a:hover {
background-color: #0000ff; /*Pure blue color */
transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out; /* fade effect on hover */
}
```